# Detect when a volume is mounted on OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, volumes

I have an OS X application that needs to respond to a volume being mounted or unmounted.

I've already solved this problem by retrieving the list of volumes periodically and checking for changes, but I'd like to know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Register to the notification center you get from `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter]` and then process the notifications you are interested in. These are the volume related ones: `NSWorkspaceDidRenameVolumeNotification`, `NSWorkspaceDidMountNotification`, `NSWorkspaceWillUnmountNotification` and `NSWorkspaceDidUnmountNotification`.

Answer (score 17):

The `NSWorkspace` approach is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.  A few lines of code later, I have a much better solution than using a timer.

```
-(void) monitorVolumes
{
    [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self selector: @selector(volumesChanged:) name:NSWorkspaceDidMountNotification object: nil];
    [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self selector: @selector(volumesChanged:) name:NSWorkspaceDidUnmountNotification object:nil];
}

-(void) volumesChanged: (NSNotification*) notification
{
    NSLog(@"dostuff");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Swift 4 version:

Declare NSWorkspace in applicationDidFinishLaunching and add observers for mount and unmount events.

```
let workspace = NSWorkspace.shared

workspace.notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didMount(_:)), name: NSWorkspace.didMountNotification, object: nil)
workspace.notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didUnMount(_:)), name: NSWorkspace.didUnmountNotification, object: nil)
```

Capture mount and unmount events in:

```
@objc func didMount(_ notification: NSNotification)  {
    if let devicePath = notification.userInfo!["NSDevicePath"] as? String {
        print(devicePath)
    }
}
@objc func didUnMount(_ notification: NSNotification)  {
    if let devicePath = notification.userInfo!["NSDevicePath"] as? String {
        print(devicePath)
    }
}
```

It will print device path e.g /Volumes/EOS_DIGITAL
Here are the constants you can read from userInfo.

```
NSDevicePath, 
NSWorkspaceVolumeLocalizedNameKey
NSWorkspaceVolumeURLKey
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you know [SCEvents](http://stuconnolly.com/blog/scevents-011/)? It allows you to be notified when the contents of an observed folder change (`/Volumes`). This way you don't have to use a timer to periodically check the contents.

Comment: Is there a reason to use this over NSWorkspace as described below? It's a 3rd party library, so the benefits would have to be significant in order to convince me to add an additional dependency to the project.