# macOS: detect when storage device is attached or detached

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, storage

It's fairly easy on macOS to detect mount and unmount operations with an `NSNotificationCenter` listener, as explained [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409458/detect-when-a-volume-is-mounted-on-os-x).

But I'm actually looking for a way to detect whether a (physical or virtual) storage device was **attached** (without mount) or **detached** (e.g. after unmount).

(It must be possible because there are a couple of applications like **Jettison** or **Mountain** that have this functionality, e.g. they will notice when the external storage device is detached, or whether it's still present for re-mounting.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [USB Connection Delegate on Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39003986/usb-connection-delegate-on-swift)

Comment: DiskArbitration framework? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/diskarbitration/1492707-daregisterdiskappearedcallback